# How I get my info with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

What I'm trying to do is to fill a table with some info from JSON file big.json, I need to do this with jQuery.

It looks like this now but not working:

```
 <div class="stink">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Car</th>
        <th>fault1</th>
        <th>fault2</th>
      </tr>

      <script>
        $.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {
          var items = [];
          $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
            items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
          });
          $( "<ul/>", {
            "class": "my-new-list",
            html: items.join( "" )
          }).appendTo( "body" );
        });
      </script>

    </table>
  </div>
```

the JSON file structure is:

```
{
    "Mercedes": {
        "fault1":"not working",
        "fault2":"key issues"       
    },
    "BMW": {
        "fault1":"not starting",
        "fault2":"control problem"
    }
}
```

How can I parse in the table those info with JQUERY ?

Comment: "Not working" is not a very good description of an error.

Comment: Could you post how you would like your final html to look like for your example?

Comment: NOT COOL VOTE DOWN WITHOUT ANY REASON!!!

Comment: Could you post the error you are getting?

Comment: @adeneo this is a dummy text, i thought it's understandable, sorry for not mentioning this.

Comment: @mituw16 no error, just not displaying anything

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado i want the info form the JSON file to be in the table from HTML, like CAR to have Mercedes, BMW and faults under faults in the table, did you get it ?

Comment: @Liza could you put an `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` before `var items ...` and tell us what happens?

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado i just added the alert, nothing happens :(

Comment: So there's a problem with your ajax call, maybe the file name is different or its inner format is corrupted. Change `getJSON` by `get` for a minute and tell us if it shows the alert

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado i changed the `get` nothing happened :( , the name and structure of JSON are correct, because i succeeded to make it parse with PHP, i just want to make it work in JQUERY too :(

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it's a dummy text, just writing "it's not working" gets us nowhere! What have you tried, what exactly is happening, did you open the console and check for errors, did you chain on a fail function to see if there are any errors etc.

Comment: You didn't load jQuery, or your json url is wrong

Comment: Your code is right, so, it's helpless. Then, considering the fact that there is no mistake at first glance, I bet you have enough skills to figure out this problem by yourself. Did you open the console? Did you paste the URL into the address bar? Remember, if you were downvoted, there must be a reason.

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado ok, so it worked, but it's displaying `[object Object]` , how can i get the actual data? i'm not expert in JQUERY, i want to do it like in php so i can `echo` inside the table, is it possible?

Comment: @Liza Is your `alert(JSON.stringify(data))` showing that? it's strange. Does that happen with `.getJSON` or with `.get` ?

Comment: You are trying to concatenate an object with a string and the default string representation is `[object Object]`. You don't have to be a jQuery expert to know that, because that's basic JavaScript. If you know PHP, then you probably also know that you get a similar behavior with arrays. If you do `echo 'data: ' . $someArray;`, then you get `data: Array` as output. You have to access the properties of the object you want to display. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11922383/218196.

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado yes, the alert is showing the data correctly, with the `getJSON`, what can i do so i can get this data to show, because i want to implement something like this http://jsfiddle.net/planetoftheweb/XcpGN/5/ but id possible without declaring the data inside the script but in a json file, how can i do this? Thanks!

Comment: @Liza I added an answer, please check it

Comment: @FelixKling thank you for explaining to me Felix :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have a table, you'd better not show your info with lists, but use the table. With this:

```
 $.getJSON( "data.json", function( data ) {

    $.each( data, function( key, obj ) {
        var items = [];
        items.push( "<td>" + key + "</td>" );   //Car name
        items.push( "<td>" + obj.fault1 + "</td>" );  //fault1
        items.push( "<td>" + obj.fault2 + "</td>" );  //fault2

        $( "<tr/>", {
            "class": "my-new-list",
            html: items.join( "" )
        }).appendTo( ".stink table" );
    }); 
});
```

I tried to modify your code at little as possible so you understand it better.

Comment: Edgar i want to really special thank you for your effort to make me understand and debug every single line of the script code. Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome Liza! Glad it helped you. Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia. My email is edgarinvillegas@hotmail.com

Comment: have another question: for that JSON above, how can i get the name of the car if i use this: `for (var i in data) {` `output="<td>"  + data[i] + "</td><td> " + data[i].fault1 + "</td><td>" + data[i].fault2+"</td>";` , How can i get the name of the car? i used `data[i]` but it's not correct :(

Comment: In that case, just `i` has the name of the car

Comment: Edgar can you help me with an answer to: `What are the different type of selectors in Jquery? ` because you seem expert in this please.

Comment: Of course! Can you provide me the question link? I can't find it

Comment: i didn't post it, is it ok if you answer here please?

Comment: Edgar are you still online?

Comment: Liza, the answer is a little long. Could you please post another question and give me the link? I have it ready :D

Comment: @Liza, the answer is a little long. Could you please post another question and give me the link? I have the answer ready to paste :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081694/having-a-theoretical-issue-in-jquery-about-selectors

Comment: the answer got deleted, don't know why, could you post it again with title `What are the differnt type of jquery selectors`, and give me the link, please?

Comment: Or you can undelete the question

Comment: @Liza Please, I need 1 more answer as accepted, post another question or undelete it

Comment: Edgar, i can't post anymore, because of the vote down i only can comment until my questions raise up with votes :( really sorry

Comment: Oh, and could you undelete that question? there's an 'undelete' link

Comment: done! maybe you can up vote my question please so i can post again. thansk!