# What are the types of jquery selectors?

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with this question and didn't have any good source, can you please help me ? What are the selectors?

Comment: This really is not a good question for SO, why could you not just check the jQuery docs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the jquery selectors (as of jQuery 1.10 and jQuery 2.0):

- **All Selector (`"*"`)**
  Selects all elements.
- **`:animated` Selector**
  Select all elements that are in the progress of an animation at the time the selector is run.
- **Attribute Contains Prefix Selector `[name|="value"]`**
  Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value either equal to a given string or starting with that string followed by a hyphen (-).
- **Attribute Contains Selector `[name*="value"]`**
  Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring.
- **Attribute Contains Word Selector `[name~="value"]`**
  Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing a given word, delimited by spaces.
- **Attribute Ends With Selector `[name$="value"]`**
  Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value ending exactly with a given string. The comparison is case sensitive.
- **Attribute Equals Selector `[name="value"]`**
  Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value exactly equal to a certain value.
- **Attribute Not Equal Selector `[name!="value"]`**
  Select elements that either don’t have the specified attribute, or do have the specified attribute but not with a certain value.
- **Attribute Starts With Selector `[name^="value"]`**
  Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.
- **`:button` Selector**
  Selects all button elements and elements of type button.
- **`:checkbox` Selector**
  Selects all elements of type checkbox.
- **`:checked` Selector**
  Matches all elements that are checked or selected.
- **Child Selector (`"parent > child"`)**
  Selects all direct child elements specified by “child” of elements specified by “parent”.
- **Class Selector (“.class”)**
  Selects all elements with the given class.
- **`:contains()` Selector**
  Select all elements that contain the specified text.
- **Descendant Selector (`"ancestor descendant"`)**
  Selects all elements that are descendants of a given ancestor.
- **:disabled Selector**
  Selects all elements that are disabled.
- **Element Selector (“element”)**
  Selects all elements with the given tag name.
- **:empty Selector**
  Select all elements that have no children (including text nodes).
- **:enabled Selector**
  Selects all elements that are enabled.
- **:eq() Selector**
  Select the element at index n within the matched set.
- **:even Selector**
  Selects even elements, zero-indexed. See also odd.
- **:file Selector**
  Selects all elements of type file.
- **:first-child Selector**
  Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.
- **:first-of-type Selector**
  Selects all elements that are the first among siblings of the same element name.
- **:first Selector**
  Selects the first matched element.
- **:focus Selector**
  Selects element if it is currently focused.
- **:gt() Selector**
  Select all elements at an index greater than index within the matched set.
- **Has Attribute Selector [name]**
  Selects elements that have the specified attribute, with any value.
- **:has() Selector**
  Selects elements which contain at least one element that matches the specified selector.
- **:header Selector**
  Selects all elements that are headers, like h1, h2, h3 and so on.
- **:hidden Selector**
  Selects all elements that are hidden.
- **ID Selector (“#id”)**
  Selects a single element with the given id attribute.
- **:image Selector**
  Selects all elements of type image.
- **:input Selector**
  Selects all input, textarea, select and button elements.
- **:lang() Selector**
  Selects all elements of the specified language.
- **:last-child Selector**
  Selects all elements that are the last child of their parent.
- **:last-of-type Selector**
  Selects all elements that are the last among siblings of the same element name.
- **:last Selector**
  Selects the last matched element.
- **:lt() Selector**
  Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.
- **Multiple Attribute Selector [name="value"][name2="value2"]
  Matches elements that match all of the specified attribute filters.
- **Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)**
  Selects the combined results of all the specified selectors.
- **Next Adjacent Selector (“prev + next”)**
  Selects all next elements matching “next” that are immediately preceded by a sibling “prev”.
- **Next Siblings Selector (“prev ~ siblings”)**
  Selects all sibling elements that follow after the “prev” element, have the same parent, and match the filtering “siblings” selector.
- **:not() Selector**
  Selects all elements that do not match the given selector.
- **:nth-child() Selector**
  Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent.
- **:nth-last-child() Selector**
  Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent, counting from the last element to the first.
- **:nth-last-of-type() Selector**
  Selects all elements that are the nth-child of their parent, counting from the last element to the first.
- **:nth-of-type() Selector**
  Selects all elements that are the nth child of their parent in relation to siblings with the same element name.
- **:odd Selector**
  Selects odd elements, zero-indexed. See also even.
- **:only-child Selector**
  Selects all elements that are the only child of their parent.
- **:only-of-type Selector**
  Selects all elements that have no siblings with the same element name.
- **:parent Selector**
  Select all elements that have at least one child node (either an element or text).
- **:password Selector**
  Selects all elements of type password.
- **:radio Selector**
  Selects all elements of type radio.
- **:reset Selector**
  Selects all elements of type reset.
- **:root Selector**
  Selects the element that is the root of the document.
- **:selected Selector**
  Selects all elements that are selected.
- **:submit Selector**
  Selects all elements of type submit.
- **:target Selector**
  Selects the target element indicated by the fragment identifier of the document’s URI.
- **:text Selector**
  Selects all elements of type text.
- **:visible Selector**
  Selects all elements that are visible.

Source: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: A link in the comments would be enough